# Stata Overlapping Histograms Different Color Where Overlap

Tags: plot, histogram, transparency, stata, transparent

Is it possible to have a different color in the portions of overlap when we have two histograms on the same plot? I have in mind something that can be done in SAS:

http://blogs.sas.com/iml/uploads/dualhist.png

In other words, one of the histograms would be semi-transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are arguably many better ways to compare distributions, this shows some small tricks:

```
sysuse auto, clear

twoway histogram mpg if foreign, width(2) start(12) blcolor(red) bfcolor(none) fraction || histogram mpg if !foreign, width(2) start(10) barw(1.8) bfcolor(none) blcolor(blue) fraction ytitle(Proportions) legend(order(1 "Foreign" 2 "Domestic") col(1) pos(1) ring(0))
```

.

Comment: What do you have in mind as far as other, better ways to compare distributions? I'm all ears.

Comment: Quantile plots, parallel dot plots, etc.

Comment: http://www.stata.com/meeting/chicago16/slides/chicago16_cox.pptx is an overview. (On slide 20, "reversing sign" is a silly mistake for "reversing order"; the file may be corrected when you read this.)

Comment: Thank you for providing that reference as well.